# How to enable SSL in kafka and zookeeper?

Tags: apache-kafka, openssl, apache-zookeeper

I need to enable SSL security in apache kafka and zookeeper? Is there any tutorial? I am facing issues with the truststore path.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can go through below links to set SSL:

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/security/security_tutorial.html#generating-keys-certs

https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/kafka/ssl.html

This is the docker image I am currently using:

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: broker
    hostname: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:9092,SSL://broker:9093
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME: kafka.server.keystore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS: kafka.key
      KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS: kafka.key
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME: kafka.server.truststore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS: kafka.key
      KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS: 1
      KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 500
      KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
    volumes:
      - ./se:/etc/kafka/secrets
```